# Css sprite doesn't stick to only the mainnav?

Tags: sprite, submenu

See http://bldd.nl/prototypes/megamenu/test23.php

I am stuck with this, if you rollover the submenu navigation you see the corresponding mainmenu rollover sprite?

How can i fix this and optimize the css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS uses a descendant selector:  `#jobs-news a:hover`.

This will match any `a:hover` inside of `#jobs-news`, even if it's actually in one of its children.

The simplest solution would be to give the root `a` elements their own class (eg, `<a class="MainLink" href="#">`), then change the hover selectors to `#jobs-news a.MainLink:hover`.

This way, it wouldn't match the subitems, since they wouldn't have the `MainLink` class.

If you don't need to support IE6, you could also use a child selector: `#jobs-news > a:hover`

Comment: man, your fast.

but i tried that with the second one
<a href="#jobs" id="testlink"> 

gonna take another look and try your suggestion.

tx in advance

Comment: slaks, your were absolute right. i am having troubles with choosing the right selector this one work tx to you
 #jobs-jobs a.testlink:hover {background:url("/assets/imgs/mainmenu4.jpg") -123px -30px no-repeat; }

Now i need to optimize and outline the submenu

Comment: You should give the `<a>` elements a class, not an ID:  `<a class="MainLink">`.  You can then write `#jobs-news a.MainLink:hover`.

Comment: tx i have given the <a> a class="spritelink".

One more question more js/jquery related. How do make sure the dropmenu stays down when you rollover the mainmenu from left to right??

Comment: oh and how would li in dropdown react on longer text. li seems to be 20px height all te time?